# Add scrollbar to grid layout in pyqt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have coded the following python program. It shows multiple icons in a grid view.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent = None):
            super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

            self.centralWidget=QWidget()
            scrollArea=QScrollArea()
            scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
            scrollArea.setWidget(self.centralWidget)
            self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
            w=QGridLayout()

            size=128
            icon=QIcon()
            mode=QIcon.Normal
            state=QIcon.Off
            pixma = QPixmap('a.png') 
            icon.addPixmap(pixma,mode,state)
            positions = [(i,j) for i in range(5) for j in range(4)]
            for position in positions:
                label=QLabel()
                label.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(size,QIcon.Normal,state))
                w.addWidget(label,*position) 

            self.centralWidget.setLayout(w)


a = QApplication(sys.argv) 
q=Main() 
q.show() 
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

I want to add a  scrollbar to the window containing icons but don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`QScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#details).
Put your `GridLayout` in a `Widget` and put that `Widget` in a `ScrollArea`.

Mind the Notes in the documentation:

> When using a scroll area to display the contents of a custom widget,
>   it is important to ensure that the size hint of the child widget is
>   set to a suitable value. If a standard QWidget is used for the child
>   widget, it may be necessary to call **QWidget::setMinimumSize()** to
>   ensure that the contents of the widget are shown correctly within the
>   scroll area.